# Strange behavior from akka actor in scala concurrent programming

Tags: akka-actor

my code:

I ran it three times with the same number, the output:

Wrong!

```
the FibonacciNumber test Started!!!
the FibonacciNumber(8) is 
 20
```

This is correct

```
the FibonacciNumber test Started!!!
the FibonacciNumber(8) is 
 21
```

Wrong!

```
the FibonacciNumber test Started!!!
the FibonacciNumber(8) is 
 19
```

Comment: @jwvh Well spotted. But at least the OP is asking for help with their solution rather than asking us to give them the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe to have a global variable that is updated by multiple actors at the same time. Multiple actors can be processing messages at the same time, and if two or more actors try to update those variables at the same time, it will not give the correct result. So with this algorithm you at very least need to make `counter` and `result` into `AtomicInteger`.

It is much better to improve the algorithm to avoid global variables. The state information should be passed between the actors using requests and replies, rather than being in variables that are accessed by multiple actors simultaneously

Comment: So I will make “val counter = new AtomicInteger(0)” and instead of letting counter do “counter += 1” now I do “counter.incrementAndGet”? Should I move the increment of counter right below “case add() =>” ?

Comment: You can call `incrementAndGet` where you currently have `+= 1`, but I strongly suggest that you re-design this code to avoid global variables. Especially if this is a class project...

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I fixed my code. Now it is giving me correct result consistently.